# Flutter: Some of the material design icons are not supported

Tags: flutter, material-design

Seems like some of the material design icons are not supported. Like I want to use `how_to_vote` icon and it's actually listed in [this page](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline) but it is not suppoted in `Icons` class. How can I use this and also why isn't it supported?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, to use material design icons you have to add the package [outline_material_icon](https://pub.dev/packages/outline_material_icons) in your pubspec.yaml. This will make available all the icons you want from [this page](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Icons class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) constants. There is no how_to_vote icon available. If you need to use that icon, download that from the material.io and add it to your app.